# jQuery display text after checked checkbox in a span

Tags: jquery, html, text, this

I have several checkboxes on a form that looks like this:

```
 <div id="checkboxlist" style="display:none;">
<ul class="checkboxlist_list">
<li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox keys" name="keys" value="150" />Keys<br></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox elec_guit" name="elec_guit" value="150" />Electric Guitar<br></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox acou_guit" name="acou_guit" value="150" />Acoustic Guitar<br></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox bass" name="bass" value="150" />Bass<br></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox drums" name="drums" value="150" />Drums<br></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

When a user checks those checkboxes, I want the text aftr it to be displayed in a "Summary" div at the bottom of my page. i.e. it will say: you have selected Keys, Electric Guitar, Bass ...for example.

Here is my current jQuery code:

```
var musicians = '';
$('.checkbox:checked').each(function(){        
    var musicianTypes = $(this).text();
    musicians += musicianTypes;
});
$(".summary_musicians").html(musicians);
```

Currently this returns no values. Can anybody tell me how to get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change your HTML to make use of the `<label>` element (good practice in general):

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox keys" name="keys" id="keys" value="150" /><label for="keys">Keys</label>
```

Then, get the text by

```
var musicianTypes = $(this).next().text();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7r2pV/

Update: .next() was kind of a simple way, but if you really want to do it right, you should find the label with the matching "for" attribute.  something like this:

```
var musicianTypes = $("label[for=" + $(this).attr("id") + "]").text();
```

Comment: Thanks for this, nice to see it comma seperated

Comment: +1 on the `label for` part, nice out of the normal thinking there!

Answer (score 3):

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BPkR6/1/)**

```
$(".summary_musicians").html(function() {
    return $('.checkbox:checked').map(function() {
               return this.nextSibling.nodeValue;
           }).get().join();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not looking for the text of the input, you're looking for the text node *after* the input.  Since your inputs are in a list item, you can get the parent text:

```
var musicians = '';
$('.checkbox:checked').each(function(){        
    var musicianTypes = $(this).parent().text();
    musicians += musicianTypes;
});
```

`$(this).closest('li')` also works

Comment: this is great, I didn't realise you could do this. Do you know how I could comma separate the list?

Comment: `nearest()`, I'm absolutely *certain*, will *not* work; `closest()`, yes; `nearest()` no (it doesn't exist as a jQuery method).

Comment: Yes, it is closest(). fixed the response.